# How to print Runtime Exception to catalina.out in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, logging, runtimeexception, catalina

This problem bother me quite a lot. 
When runtime exception, like Null Pointer or Incompatible Class, happens, my tomcat always quit silently, leaving nothing in log. This make debugging much harder.
So I wanna these runtime printed into catalina.out, is any solution available?

Comment: Make sure that you are not catching the exceptions and eating them up. Unchecked exceptions should be logged in catalina.out

Comment: What version of Tomcat? What logging framework are you using (default logging or log4j/slf4j)? Have you modified the default logging configuration? Does your webapp install any error handlers? Have you looked in any other log files under `$CATALINA_BASE/logs`?